# swiftui - how to "skip" the list display when all rows not displayed

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a swiftui app and have been beating my head over this issue.

What I have is a page with a list. The list is populated by an array of json documents. I process each document, deciding based off of certain characteristics, whether the list should display that "row" or not.

If the list is "empty" do not display it, instead display an image. There are two possibilities of the list being "empty" - the first is obvious, there are no rows at all in the array (the count of the array is 0). That one works well. The second one, however, has been a beast for me to figure out due to nature of the programming language. The second one is considered "empty" if the array actually has documents, but none of them qualify to display a single row. It is this scenario I need help with.

I have tried everything I can think of to figure this out, but hit road blocks with each direction. The obvious solution would be to not put the elements in the array if they can't be displayed and simply have an array with qualifying displayed rows. Without going into detail, let's just say that isn't an option.

So my question is: How do I hide the list and show the icon if the array has elements but nothing qualifies to be displayed (right now a big white rectangular empty list is displayed instead and it looks horrible).

Here is the snipit of code:

```
      struct listRow: View {

         var body: some View {
          ... all checks for every row in here fail so it does nothing
         }

      }

      struct MainView: View {
          var body: some View {
               if (<myArray>.count == 0) {
                  <displayMyImage>
               }
               else {
                  List(<myArray>) {
                        arrayItem in
                        listRow(arrayItem)
                        }
  
                    }
                    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
               }
        }
     }
```

So assume from the above code that the array has 50 json documents in it, but none of them qualify. What I end up with is a large white rectangle where the list rows are supposed to be. I can't use "the array has 0 items so don't show it". The "Check" simply calls a structure conforming to the View protocol and does nothing (it does checks, but all of them fail so nothing is produced). Not sure how to tackle this one as everything in the list needs to conform to the view protocol.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you should a [mre] with _real_ code? No one can run the pseudocode you've included. In general, I'd say use something like `reduce` to check the whole array and return a `Bool` based on the child values, but since there's no code to try that on, I can't write an answer.

Comment: I have updated the code to be a bit more complete as to your request. The listRow structure is complex and has a LOT of stuff in it, but if you want to reproduce, simply have it do nothing. As for the list array, simply create any type of array that has, say, 20 values (doesn't have to be json struct, simply create an array of integers if you want). Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately what you've added doesn't clarify the issue at all. @vadian gave you as reasonable as possible an answer given the limited scope of what you've provided. If anyone else were to give an answer, it's unlikely they'd guess the complexity that you're saying exists but isn't represented in the code.

Comment: I'm not sure where the posted block of code as a solution went, but what was provided worked great! I was misinterpreting the post. Whoever posted that, thank you, it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Filter did the trick. Here is what someone else provided that I am posting as the solution (the solution posted disappeared):

let qualifiedArray = getMessagesApi.dataArray.gpData.filter( { shouldDisplayRow(gpRow: $0) })

Comment: @vadian sounds like you should un-delete your answer